# Problems with bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a problem with the code.

When I start the bot and type $start it works but it stops after few seconds.

I'm a beginner, so I don’t know why this is happening.

Here is my code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import colorsys
from discord import utils
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings
from discord.utils import get
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    role_id = settings['roleid']
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(int(role_id))
    color_rgb = 0
    while True:
        while True:
            color_rgb = color_rgb + 5
            await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, color_rgb, 0))
            if (color_rgb == 255):
                print('done')
                break
        while True:
            color_rgb = color_rgb - 5
            await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(color_rgb, 255, 0))
            if (color_rgb == 0):
                print ('done')
                break
        while True:
            color_rgb = color_rgb + 5
            await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 255, color_rgb))
            if (color_rgb == 255):
                print ('done')
                break
        while True:
            color_rgb = color_rgb - 5
            await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, color_rgb, 255))
            if (color_rgb == 0):
                print ('done')
                break
        while True:
            color_rgb = color_rgb + 5
            await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(color_rgb, 0, 255))
            if (color_rgb == 255):
                print ('done')
                break
        while True:
            color_rgb = color_rgb - 5
            await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 0, color_rgb))
            if (color_rgb == 0):
                print ('done')
                break
bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of all the breaks, you can try this after your `color_rgb = 0` statement:

```
while True:
    for c in range(0,256,5):
        await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, c, 0))
        print("done")

    for c in range(0,256,5):
        await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255-c, 255, 0))
        print("done")

    for c in range(0,256,5):
        await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 255, c))
        print("done")

    for c in range(0,256,5):
        await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(0, 255-c, 255)
        print("done")

    for c in range(0,256,5):
        await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(c, 0, 255))
        print("done")

    for c in range(0,256,5):
        await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(255, 0, 255-c))
        print("done")
    print("all done")
```

Comment: This is intended to smoothly change rgb values. But the bot stops changing colors after several color changing circles

Comment: It`s cycled between red and yellow
https://youtu.be/4CpoTvl7oaA

Comment: I think yes, 18 times

Comment: no i started it once. last messages were test messages

Comment: ok, i edited my answer. give it a try to be sure the last break didn't end the complete while True loop

Comment: It stoped again

Comment: after printing `"all done"`? hm maybe thats because discord bots dont like adding a forever loop to them. Maybe you can try to use this structure for your bot: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/background_task.py

Comment: Ok i will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Hey I read some stuff about it. Discord does not want "Rainbow Roles" and also limits the role edits to 1000 per day.

Have a read here: [https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360067748172-Increase-Role-Edit-rate-limit-to-86400#:~:text=The%20rate%20limit%20for%20editing,1000%20requests%20per%2024%20hours](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360067748172-Increase-Role-Edit-rate-limit-to-86400#:%7E:text=The%20rate%20limit%20for%20editing,1000%20requests%20per%2024%20hours).

And here: https://twitter.com/discord/status/1055182857709256704?lang=en

What you could do is change the color up to 1000 times per day, maybe only when you're logged in